# How to catch the xhr object for Backbone.save

Tags: javascript, jquery, backbone.js, underscore.js, marionette

```
App.commands.setHandler "when:fetched", (entities, callback) ->
  xhrs = _.chain([entities]).flatten().pluck("_fetch").value()
  $.when(xhrs...).done ->
    callback()
```

we have the above code to catch the xhr object from fetch calls. How can i catch the xhr object from save method (for all post,put and delete types). I am getting undefined for the save method.

Answer (score 1):

backbone save method returns a `jqXHR` if validation is successful and `false` otherwise

example :

```
   var myxhr = myModel.save({},{
    success : function(){
    alert(myxhr); //your xhrboject here
         }
    });
```

Comment: I am looking for a common function like "fetch" above where i need to pass the xhr object and on "done" then execute the success function. Till the response comes it has to wait to call the success function.

Comment: I am looking for a common function like "fetch" above where i need to pass the xhr object and on "done" execute the success function. Till the response comes it has to wait to call the success function. Like
    $.when(savexhr).done(){success()}.fail(){failure()}            

But here "savexhr" is returning as undefined and always the success function is executing before the ajax call completes.

Comment: so you want the success function to be executed only after the response is received?